# PIGLatin How to compare 2 CSV with too many rows and columns

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a scenario with PIG in terms of comparing 2 CSV files. Basically, what it should do is read the 2 CSV files, compare it to each other, and create a log file which contains the ROW Number, and if possible Column Number of the different value.

Sample output :

Found 1 different value :

Row : #8764

Column : #67

Expected : 8984954

Actual : 0

Is there a way in PIG to do this?

Comment: is there a common key? or a line number?

Comment: If you had some common key (like a line number) you could join the read files based on that and then write a UDF that compares the two lines and outputs the column(s) where they differ. Then at the end you filter for rows with changes and output these.

Comment: for the given example, there's no common key.